# Absence of "Build Quality" in new Visual Studio Online Build System

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

What happened to the "Build Quality" in the "new" Visual Studio Online build system (the modular build system released in summer 2015)? Seems i can work with Build Quality in UI and API for old XAML- based builds but not with builds based on new build definitions. Is there any alternative concept or did i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The release management tool knows where the build has been deployed and takes over from the status.

You can use Release Management locally to do this, or you can wait for the new release system that was announced at Build and will be built into TFS & VSO.